# Is it possible to find out the PacBio chemistry from the PacBio Sequel BAM's header?

Tags: sam, pacbio

Is it possible to find out the PacBio chemistry from the PacBio Sequel BAM's header? E.g. whether it was produced with P5-C3 or P6-C4? I checked mine but I haven't found it but maybe it's hidden in one of the tags whose meaning I don't know yet, like SEQUENCINGKIT=100-861-800?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PacBio Sequel BAM format manual](http://pacbiofileformats.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/BAM.html), you can find information on the [chemistry version](https://www.pacb.com/blog/new-chemistry-software-sequel-system-improve-read-length-lower-project-costs/) in the header entries `@RG` (read group), tag `DS` (description), entry `BASECALLERVERSION` .

In case of future very PacBio-specific questions, you can contact Liz Tseng on Twitter (@magdoll), one of the most responsive PacBio developers. They also have a [dedicated SeqAnswers forum](http://seqanswers.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=39), which is directly monitored by them and you are very likely to get a fast and accurate answer.

Comment: I have 5.0.0.6236 for BASECALLERVERSION. Does it mean chemistry P5-C3 was used?

Comment: This surely means chemistry is higher than P4-C2 / 2.0, which is not supported in pbbam. The logical answer would be then yes, P5-C3 chemistry (or higher) was used.